# Why do I keep getting this Authorization Error: "Error 401: invalid_client / The OAuth client was not found."?

Tags: wordpress, oauth, authorization, clientid

I have read through the (many years old) solutions posted to this problem, but none have worked:

- I do NOT have spaces before or after the Client ID or Client Secret.
- I do not see any option for entering a "Product" name anywhere.
- I have tried refreshing and getting a new Client Secret key.

Note: Every time I get the error message and then navigate back to my Wordpress plugin settings page, I see that "http://" has been added to the beginning of the Client ID. This seems strange and possibly part of the problem?

I am using WP Mail SMTP on a basic Wordpress site hosted with GoDaddy, in case that helps pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Did you turn on WP SMTP Mail Loggin? What was in the logs?

Comment: Thank you for the response! By "turn on," do you mean "activate"? I am unskilled in all things programming, but if that is what you mean, yes, I made this the only active mail plugin. I didn't seen any logs. When I did the email test, the plugin gave me the message that the email had successfully sent. No mention of errors. Also, when I test it on my webpage, it displays "thank you, your message has been sent." But I never receive the emails - not in the junk or spam folders, and no matter what email address I try sending to.

Comment: I just saw this when opening my plug-ins page on wp-admin:                                                           Mailer: Gmail
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

Comment: I gave up using both Gmail API and "WP Forms" - both are sinkholes where no actual human is available to help. I don't want to rely on companies like that. I found a solution using a plug-in combo of "Participants Database" and "Easy WP SMTP." GoDaddy provided me with technical assistance.